# Align text left in libgdx TextButton

Tags: java, json, libgdx, scene2d

is there a way to align the text in a textbutton to left (or right) instead of center? I'v looked for it, but I cant seem to find it. Is it something that you can do with a .json skin file, and if so, how?

Thanks, if I was unprecise please let me know :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes you can align the text to the left side of the button, see example:

```
someButton.getLabel().setAlignment(Align.left);
```

so basically you have to align the button´s label to the left side inside the button. Obviously you can do the same for right, top, bottom alignment etc.

Answer (score 0):

This also does the same thing, "adjusting the label position".

```
    Skin theSkin= new Skin();  
//Create a button style
    TextButton.TextButtonStyle textButtonStyle = new TextButton.TextButtonStyle();
    textButtonStyle.pressedOffsetY=-4.0f;
    textButtonStyle.unpressedOffsetY=-4.0f;
theSkin.add("default", textButtonStyle);
TextButton   theButton = new TextButton("New",theSkin);
```